# Apache Camel AHC component examples test-sources jar

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel

I am creating a POC using Apache Camel 2.8 and its AHC component.
I could not find any examples on Apache Camel's website's Examples section for the same.

Also on the AHC component detail page http://camel.apache.org/ahc.html examples only show request being sent to a single URL.For sending requests to multiple URLs in aysnchronous manner and handling their callbacks and responses I cannot see any examples.

If anybody has worked on this and can point me to where I can find the desired examples I would be very much thankful.

Also I was looking out for the unit tests for Camel's AHC component in my local maven repository but could not find the test-sources JAR file.From where and how can I download the same? Unit tests would help in how to use the AHC component API.

I could find the test source code at this location 
https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel/trunk/components/camel-ahc/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/ahc

Is there any way in which I can download all the tests in the form of a JAR file?

Thanks,

Jignesh

Answer (score 2):

The camel-ahc component is asynchronous by default.

See more details here and the links from that page: http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-routing-engine.html

So if you for example have a Camel route that does a request/reply using AHC, then you can do route messages concurrently, and the camel-ahc runs asynchronously.

Comment: Hi Claus.Thanks for your reply.I have one more question: Can I use Apache Camel for a real-time application for e.g. a flight-booking engine like kayak.com where, I request for data to various providers like Saber and display aggregated results to the user? The performance has to be in micro-seconds assuming that the providers send responses instantaneously.

Comment: Yeah in fact Sabre is using AMQ + SMX + Camel in their solution. See case study on http://fusesource.com/resources/collateral/

Comment: You can download the test source code using subversion or git.

Comment: You can use the multicast EIP to request from multiple providers, and aggregate responses to a single combined response. The multicast can also run in parallel, and it support timeout. The Camel in Action book covers this with example in chapter 10.